# Create pandas data from one date and timestrings without colons

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

I want to read times from a file that includes [GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation) times, among a lot of other data. The expected result is a pandas array (Index or Series) with datetime datatype, with the date of the dataset applied.

In an intermediate step, I have a list of timestamps in the format `hhmmss` with some invalid data mixed in:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

date = dt.date(2023, 5, 9)
times_from_file = [",,,,,,"¸ "123456", "123457", "123458", "123459", "123500"]
```

I can get the desired output with this lengthy code snippet:

```
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(
    times_from_file, format="%H%M%S", errors="coerce"
).map(
    lambda datetime: pd.NaT
    if pd.isnull(datetime)
    else dt.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time())
)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex([                'NaT', '2023-05-09 12:34:56',
               '2023-05-09 12:34:57', '2023-05-09 12:34:58',
               '2023-05-09 12:34:59', '2023-05-09 12:35:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

However, this looks overly complicated. I was hoping this could be solved with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) instead but unfortunately that doesn't allow passing a format string. Even the `na_action` keyword of [`pandas.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) is ignored – that's why I used `if pd.isnull(datetime)` instead.

Is there a simpler way to do this, preferably leveraging purpose-built Pandas functions or methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `times_from_file` as a Series if it's not already the case:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2023-05-09 ' + pd.Series(times_from_file), format="%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S", errors='coerce')

0                   NaT
1   2023-05-09 12:34:56
2   2023-05-09 12:34:57
3   2023-05-09 12:34:58
4   2023-05-09 12:34:59
5   2023-05-09 12:35:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: But if you read your data from a file with `read_csv` or `read_excel`, you can use `date_parser` parameter.

Comment: I'm using a custom parser that relies on Python string processing.

Comment: So use the date as prefix then convert the string with `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: A few days ago I saw a similar solution to a similar problem and discarded it because I thought string concatenation would introduce a significant slowdown. However, this solution is a few times faster than mine with 6000 elements in the input list.